# How can I get the subgraphs number from this graph with this specific edges

Tags: graph-theory

How many subgraphs are there with this edges in red 
[graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zDo.png)

I tried and found $5$ from $15$ since have $15$ edges and we only need $5$ edges but the problem that the question is for $5$ specified edges I don't think it's a correct answer.

What do you think guys ?  thank you

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how many subgraphs of the pictured graph exist where all of the red edges are used in each subgraph?

Comment: yes exactly thats what i am looking for

Comment: If so, notice that since each vertex is used by at least one of the red edges, every such subgraph must use every vertex.  The only things which may be removed then are black edges.  How many ways can you choose which of the ten black edges if any are removed?  *Hint:* Think about power sets or about multiplication principle.

Comment: thanks bro if i got you right then its 2^10